# How can I track the progress of the Parallelism TS for GCC

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17, issue-tracking

The [Parallelism TS has been standardized](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0024r2.html) in C++17 but is not yet available in GCC according to [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support). I assume some work has been started on it, but I can't figure out how to track progress or be notified when it's done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to track updates is to look through GCC BugTracker (https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/) and Mailing List Archives (https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/libstdc++/).

The latest info that I've found is that they have patch for that already, but they've faced with some licensing issueses which they are trying to hanlde (https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/libstdc++/2018-11/msg00017.html, https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/libstdc++/2018-11/msg00018.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can monitor this page: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html

This provides the Implementation Status of different features of different versions of C++.

The page shows there is no support for this even in the latest version of GCC (9.1)

[image]

Comment: I was hoping for more info about the internal implementation progress.